# .stl files not appearing in import search window

Tags: import, file-format, stl

Specifically I am trying to import a HeroForge digital miniature into Blender to manually edit.
Literally downloaded blender just for this so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, I'm new to the program.

I have downloaded the HeroForge file which is in .stl format and it sits in my downloads folder here:

[image]

When I search for stl files to import i go to file>import>stl>downloads and it appears empty:

[image]

I have tried opening the file directly with Blender, which causes Blender to launch, however it does not open the selected stl file, but a new blank file instead.

I've googled but the only things that pop up are people who have issues with how their files appear after import.

Comment: You are doing it correctly, there are two thing you should check. 1. If maybe the file is corrupted.
2. You should copy the file to another location and try again

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)